# Curl equivalent of php header

Tags: php, curl

I am struggling on how to convert this to php_curl :

```
    <?php

    $auth_endpoint = "https://api.ffm.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code";
    $client_id = "myidishere";
    $returnurl = "http://127.0.0.1:8998/returnurl.php";
    $auth_request = $auth_endpoint . "&client_id=" . urlencode($client_id). "&redirect_uri=" .  urlencode($returnurl);      
    header("Location:" . $auth_request);

?>
```

Comment: Can you show your existing attempt to port it?

Comment: Why would you need to convert this, tho? You're building a URL string and issuing a 302 redirect. I don't see anything for CURL to do here.